# Where can i get free GSM libraries/components for delphi or python?

Tags: python, delphi, gsm

Where can i get good free GSM libraries for **Delphi** or **Python**? Libraries i can use to send and receive sms's on my application?

Gath

Answer (score 2):

For free and open source [AsyncPro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/)>

Not free but the components has active development [nrComm Lib](http://www.deepsoftware.com/nrcomm)

Another solution to use SMS gateway, such as [ClickAtell](http://www.clickatell.com/), with solution you can send sms using a simple post command to the gateway url or webservices.

Answer (score 1):

[Get it here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/) - completely free (previously commercial components):

Answer (score 1):

Another SMS gateway with a Python interface is TextMagic.

Read my response to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716946/how-do-i-enable-sms-notifications-in-my-web-app/1071496#1071496)

Answer (score 0):

A [PyPi search turns up several promising Python SMS libraries](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=sms&submit=search). Some of them talk to a GSM modem, others work through web SMS gateways, and there's even one to interface with Apple's Sudden Motion Sensor.

Answer (score 0):

I've always enjoyed [this application](http://fma.sf.net/) with my Sony-Ericsson devices: