# GSM Modem send SMS

Tags: delphi, serial-port, gsm

I have a GSM Modem manufactured by ZTE Corporation. I want to develop an application to send SMS messages via this device. The problem is I can't connect to the COM Port. All what I can  see in the Device Manager is the HSPADataCard Diagnostics Interface on COM22 and HSPADataCard NMEA Device on COM24. I have tried to connect using putty on both ports but I failed.

I was wondering if I could use TAPI to send SMS. Any ideas on how to achieve my goal are welcomed.

Also, do you know any library for Delphi ?

Comment: do you see any serial port that is being added under Ports (COM & LPT) in devicemanager? the NMEA device is GPS. I see that this is a 3G usb stick, maybe you are lacking a driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [nrComm Lib](http://www.deepsoftware.ru/nrcomm/) provides possibilities for sending SMS messages over GSM modems.

Lots of other serial communication options and up to date with the most recent Delphi versions.

Answer (score 4):

TurboPower AsyncPro has [SMS component](http://tpapro.sourceforge.net/ApdPager.html). It is not hard to send SMS in code, and some of the links might help you with this. However, for this to work you need to establish communication with your GSM modem via some COM port (or USB virtual COM port), and receive a reply for AT commands typed in your terminal application. If your GSM modem does not provide this, then all proposed methods will fail.

- [Where can i get free GSM libraries/components for delphi or python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657100/where-can-i-get-free-gsm-libraries-components-for-delphi-or-python)
- http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp
- http://www.torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=sms&Title=Yes

Answer (score 0):

Activexpert is another solution for you. I've used it and found easier to implement than some other tools I tried.